# How to grab instagram users based on a hashtag?

Tags: instagram, hashtag

is there a way to grab instagram users based on a specific hashtag ?
I run contests based on re posting photos with specified hashtag then randomly pick a winner, i need a tool that can grab the usernames of those who reposted that photo and used that hashtag.

Answer (score 0):

You can query instagram using the API. There are official clients for both [python](https://github.com/Instagram/python-instagram) and [ruby](https://github.com/Instagram/instagram-ruby-gem).

You didn't specify what language/platform you are using, so I'll give you the generic approach.

1. Query instagram using the [Tag Recent Media endpoint](http://instagram.com/developer/endpoints/tags/).
2. In the response, you will receive a user object that has the user's username, id, profile url, and so on. This should be enough to do what you are describing.

As far as tools, there aren't great options to probably do things exactly how you want. If you just want a simple contest, you could use [statigram](http://statigr.am/instagram-contest-toolkit), but it's not free.

If you roll your own solution, I highly recommend you also do the following:

1. Implement a rate limiting mechanism such as a task queue so you don't exceed your API calls (5000 per hour for most calls). Also useful for failures/network hicups, etc.
2. Have users authenticate so you can use OAuth to extend your API calls to 5000/per user/hour to get around #1.
3. Try the subscribe API if there won't be many items. You can subscribe to a specific tag as well, and you will get a change notification. At that point though you need to retrieve the actual media item(s), and this can cost a lot of API calls depending on how frequent and what volume these changes occur.
4. If your users don't have much photos/relatively small/known in advance, you can actually query the user's recent media instead and filter in your own code by hash tag.